# Render comment edit form in block

Tags: 7, forms, comments

I am using following code to render node comment form in a block:

```
$comment_form = drupal_get_form('comment_node_<node_type>_form', (object) array('nid' => $nid));
print drupal_render($comment_form);
```

It is working fine.

Now I need to check if a user has already commented on the node. If the user has not commented than I will show him/her this comment add form.

But in case, the user has already placed a comment for the node, I want to show him/her the edit form for his/her comment, where he/she can make changes and save thus updating the existing comment instead of saving new.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this case, sharing so that anyone who need similar solution can use it.

Anyone who has similar issue can use the solution below:

```
<?php       
    $comment = comment_load($comment_id); // $comment_id = cid of comment whose edit form need to be open

    module_load_include('inc', 'comment', 'comment.pages');
    $form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment); 

    return drupal_render($form);
?>
```